# Loading external Website via AMPscript in Cloudpage

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I trie to develop my cloudpages on an external server and load the extrnal site via AMPscript into the Marketing Cloud Cloud Page.

when I try it this way:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1
</head>
%%=TreatAsContent(HttpGet(Concat("http://nx-mcloud.bplaced.net/AMPScript/test.html",GUID())))=%%
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

it does not work. Could anyone help me with that? When I try to load the cloud page there is always an internal error.

Thx

Comment: why are you concatting your webpage with a GUID at the end? This is likely producing an invalid url which is why you are getting the error

Comment: Yeah, that was the mistake

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following code, keep the output in Body tags and also modify your external web page to be able to print the right data.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1
</head>
<body>
%%=TreatAsContent(HttpGet("http://nx-mcloud.bplaced.net/AMPScript/test.html"))=%%
</body>
</html>
```